# Where to see "View Source" of rendered inline Visualforce page that is embeded in a standard page?

Tags: inline-visualforce

I have searched the "View Source" of the Account detail page thinking that i can see the rendered HTML details of inline visualforce page too. But after doing exhaustive search i did not find anything that related to inline vf pages in view source. Where can i find the details of inline vf page view source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome, when you right-click over the inline Visualforce page (which is in an iframe) these context menu items are added:

- Reload Frame
- View Frame Source
- View Frame Info

and the second option shows you the source HTML.